# How to Crop Image Based on Google Vision API Bounding Poly Normalized Vertices using OpenCV for Python

Tags: python, opencv, google-vision

I'm working on implementing the Google Vision Detect Multiple Objects API in Python (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/object-localizer)

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to use the boundingPoly nomralizedVerticies that are returned in the response to determine how to crop the original image using OpenCV.

Example Response

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "localizedObjectAnnotations": [
        {
          "mid": "/m/0bt_c3",
          "name": "Book",
          "score": 0.8462029,
          "boundingPoly": {
            "normalizedVertices": [
              {
                "x": 0.1758254,
                "y": 0.046406608
              },
              {
                "x": 0.84299797,
                "y": 0.046406608
              },
              {
                "x": 0.84299797,
                "y": 0.9397349
              },
              {
                "x": 0.1758254,
                "y": 0.9397349
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update**

So these are the coordinates that I'm working with.

```
points = [
          (
             0.17716026,
             0.04550384
          ),
          (
             0.8430133,
             0.04550384
          ),
          (
             0.8430133,
             0.9376166
          ),
          (
             0.17716026,
             0.9376166
          )
        ]
```

They are referring to this image.
[image]

When I run my code using the answer provided by @MSS and use it to draw contours I get the below image.

```
from this import d
from pyimagesearch import imutils
from skimage import exposure
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
from skimage.transform import rotate
from rembg import remove


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-q", "--query", required = True,
    help = "Path to the query image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
image = cv2.imread(args["query"])
orig = image.copy()

IMAGE_SHAPE = image.shape
points = [
          (
             0.17716026,
             0.04550384
          ),
          (
             0.8430133,
             0.04550384
          ),
          (
             0.8430133,
             0.9376166
          ),
          (
             0.17716026,
             0.9376166
          )
        ]

coords = []
for point in points:
    pixels = tuple(round(coord * dimension) for coord, dimension in zip(point, IMAGE_SHAPE))
    coords.append(pixels)


points = np.array(coords)

cv2.drawContours(image, [points], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1) 
cv2.imshow("Image", image) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the image that is output. So it appears as if the cropping is off. The cropped image that is output matches the contour as well.

[image]

You can see in this screenshot that it's indicating that it's finding the object correctly.

[image]

**Update**
Ultimately the issue was that the image was flipped for some reason. I had to read in the IMAGE_SHAPE and do this.

```
IMAGE_SHAPE = image.shape[:2]
IMAGE_SHAPE = (IMAGE_SHAPE[1], IMAGE_SHAPE[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unnormalize the coordinates based on the size of the original image in order to obtain the true coordinates.

```
(number_of_rows, number_of_columns) = image.shape[:2]

x_unormalized = round(x_normalized * number_of_rows)
y_unnormalized = round(y_normalized * number_of_columns)

...

cropped_image = image[y_unnormalized:y_unnormalized + h, x_unormalized:x_unormalized + w]
```

This is by considering that the normalized values are obtained by:

```
normalized_value = true_value/max(all_values)
```

If some other normalization is applied, then you have to apply the inverse of that particular normalization.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the working code. I have tested it and it is working fine. I think you considered incorrect coordinate values.

```
# from this import d
# from pyimagesearch import imutils
# import numpy as np
# import argparse
# from rembg import remove
#from skimage import exposure
#from skimage.transform import rotate
import cv2


image = cv2.imread("Path to image.jpg")
orig = image.copy()

(number_of_rows, number_of_columns) = image.shape[:2]
points = [
          (
             0.17716026,
             0.04550384
          ),
          (
             0.8430133,
             0.04550384
          ),
          (
             0.8430133,
             0.9376166
          ),
          (
             0.17716026,
             0.9376166
          )
        ]

first_point_y = round(points[0][0] * number_of_columns)
first_point_x = round(points[0][1] * number_of_rows)
second_point_y  = round(points[2][0] * number_of_columns)
second_point_x = round(points[2][1] * number_of_rows)

# coords = []
# for point in points:
#     pixels = tuple(round(coord * dimension) for coord, dimension in zip(point, IMAGE_SHAPE))
#     coords.append(pixels)


# points = np.array(coords)

image = cv2.rectangle(image, (first_point_y, first_point_x), (second_point_y, second_point_x), (0, 255, 0), 1)
# cv2.drawContours(image, [points], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1) 
cv2.imshow("Image", image) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here is the output image:

[image]

Comment: This solution seems to generate the same points as the below solution, but neither are generating the correctly cropped region or contours.

Comment: @JamesParker My answer was just showing the way of doing it and was not the exact answer. In the updated answer, I have posted the correct solution and it is working fine. I think your rectangle is out of place because of considering the wrong coordinate values, i.e., `x` for `y` and `y` for `x`.

Answer (score 1):

First convert normalized coordinates to pixel coordinates as follows:

```
test_coord = (0.5, 0.3)

IMAGE_SHAPE = (1920, 1080) # EXample


def to_pixel_coords(relative_coords):
    return tuple(round(coord * dimension) for coord, dimension in zip(relative_coords, IMAGE_SHAPE))
```

After getting the pixel coordinates , lets say they are (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) and (x4,y4).
Then you can crop the original image as follows:

```
top_left_x = min([x1,x2,x3,x4])
top_left_y = min([y1,y2,y3,y4])
bot_right_x = max([x1,x2,x3,x4])
bot_right_y = max([y1,y2,y3,y4])

img[top_left_y:bot_right_y+1, top_left_x:bot_right_x+1] # added 1 pixel more as last one is excluded in slicing.
```

Comment: In your example is relative_cords referring to a single point (x,y) or would I pass a list/array of coordinates into that? [(x,y),(x,y),(x,y),(x,y)]?

Comment: This solution seems to generate the same points as the above solution, but neither are generating the correctly cropped region or contours.